# Spring Boot: set server.address from command line in Intelij Idea

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

I did this

-Dserver.address=`hostname -I|cut -f5 -d ' '`

in configuration, in "VM Options"

but I got Error

Unrecognized option: -I|cut
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

I need help, please

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get the unrecognised option error is because you use spaces in your JVM argument. You will need to enclose it with quotes. The [official JVM docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html#BABDJJFI) say:

> -Dproperty=value.  Sets a system property value. The property variable is a string with no spaces that represents the name of the property. The value variable is a string that represents the value of the property. If value is a string with spaces, then enclose it in quotation marks (for example -Dfoo="foo bar").

So in your example that should be something like:

`-Dserver.address="hostname -I|cut -f5 -d ' '"`

However I'm not 100% if you are able to use a command as a value. As far as I know it can only be a 'static' value.